# Intent couldnt be initialized even after multiple tries

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created this small program but i cant seem to make it run. It gives an error saying that intent hasnt been initialized. What should i do?

```
Spinner mySpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.which));
    myAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner1.setAdapter(myAdapter1);

    mySpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                   View view,
                                   int position,
                                   long id) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, intent.class);
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    break;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

EDIT 1 : Added few more lines of code to make the whole situation clearer

Comment: Why this  intent.class ? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: He wants to make dynamic intent using single intent variable.

Comment: @HemantParmar I am trying to switch the screen on spinner selected item

Comment: ok than have a look my post, you can pass your activity based on spinner position.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the below line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, intent.class)
```

You have to pass the `class` of a valid Activity here, not the class of the `intent`.

You get the error because `intent` object is not yet created. So you can't use `intent` in that statement. You can't access an object until the object is created. In this statement you are trying to create the `intent` object, by using `intent`. That's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
  mySpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                   View view,
                                   int position,
                                   long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, intent.class);
```

You are passing wrong argument in 2nd. Please pass proper Activity class where you want to redirect your user.

```
           Intent intent; //Initialize it later as per your switch  case condition.
            switch (position) {
                case 1: //Initialize as per your condition
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    break;
            }
if(intent!=null) //Check here if its not null. Else it will crash your app.
            startActivity(intent);
```

You can also do like this.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument you are passing is wrong, intent require valid activity class in second argument while redirect to activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, intent.class);
```

remove your line with this

```
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);                    
            break;
        }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: share your log cat.